# An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest was not found:

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I developed application in asp.net-core 2.0 preview1.
I developed on windows with Visual Studio 2017.

Now I want to deploy it to Linux server using Docker.

I created Docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 44305
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Aplication.dll"]
```

After that running commands:

```
dotnet build -o obj/Docker/publish -c Release
dotnet publish -o obj/Docker/publish -c Release
docker build -t testapi-api .
docker run -p 44305:80 --name api testapi-api
```

Afer the last command `run` I am getting next error:

```
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Aplication.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.0-preview1-final'
    path: 'lib/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'
  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
    manifest.win7-x64.xml;manifest.win7-x86.xml;manifest.osx-x64.xml;manifest.linux-x64.xml
```

I am new with asp.net-core and especially with Docker. So any help with this is great.

Comment: Did you try dotnet restore?

Comment: yes I tried it, but still the same error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify **-r linux-x64** parameter in dotnet publish command like that:

```
dotnet publish -o obj/Docker/publish -c Release -r linux-x64
```

This will make a standalone deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this image "2.0.0-preview1". Basically change the first line to FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.0-preview1, if your local has preview 1 dotnet core.

If it not works, check your local dotnet core version, it it points to 2.0.0-preview2-final, then change all your references pointing to 2.0.0-preview2-final in csproj file, then use the 2.0.0-preview2 image. It would help you I hope.